# How do you synchronise projects to GitHub with Android Studio?

Tags: android, github, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am trying to synchronise a project that I have on in my Android Studio folder to GitHub, but I am not fully sure what to do other than adding my credentials in the options menu. Could someone give me a quick guide, please?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Open the project you want to push in Android Studio.

Click `VCS -> Enable version Control Integration -> Git`

There doesn't seem to be a way to add a remote through the GUI. So open Git Bash in the root of the project and do `git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>`

Now when you do `VCS -> Commit changes -> Commit & Push` you should see your remote and everything should work through the GUI.

---

If you are getting the error: `fatal: remote <remote_name> already exists` that means        you already added it. To see your remotes do `git remote -v` and `git remote rm <remote_name>` to remove.

---

See these pages for details:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html

http://gitref.org/remotes/

Comment: When i do VCS -> Commit changes  i get **No changes detected**

Comment: If the file names in the project window are red that means they aren't being tracked. Right click the file then Git -> Add. Now changes in that file should be detected.

Comment: @jsc0 I think it can only add the `app` module at the maximum. To add all of them, open terminal and `git add .` at the project dir. Which one is the best practice? To add a project or to add a module into the version control?

Comment: Can I push the same project to 2 github repo? I was not able to.

Comment: I know of one way to add the remote through the GUI. If you do a push and you haven't set up credentials and the address for remote, then it will prompt you. You will see master -> Define remote and the "Define remote" part will appear as a link. Click on it and the rest will be self explanatory if you have used Git before.

Comment: Great explanations.  This video could also be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldmc757EXaE

Comment: Though not entirely related on this one, but in case you need your project to be on BitBucket altassian here's how you integrate bitbucket remote repo with Android Studio: http://www.goprogramming.space/connecting-android-studio-project-with-bitbucket/

Comment: `VCS -> Enable version Control Integration` doesn't exist for me. All I have in the VCS menu is VCS Operations, Apply Patch and Apply Patch from Clipboard.

Answer (score 66):

Following method is a generic way of pushing an Android Studio project to a GIT based repository solely using GUI.This has been tested with a GIT repository hosted in **Visual Studio Online** and should virtually work with **GitHub** or any other GIT based version control provider.

**Note: *If you are using GitHub 'Share on GitHub' is the easiest option as stated in other answers.***

1. **Enable the GIT Integration plugin**

   File (main menu) >> Settings >> Search for GitHub Integration
   [image]

---

2. **Enable Version Control Integration for The Project**

   VCS (main menu) >> Enable Version Control Integration >> Select GIT 
   [image]

---

3. **Add project file to Local repository**

   Right Click on project >> GIT  >> Add
   [image]

---

4. **Commit Added Files**

   Open the Version Control windows (Next to terminal window) >> Click commit 
   button

   [image]

   In the prompt window select "commit and push"

   [image]

---

5. **Defining Remote**

   After analyzing code android studio will prompt to review or commit code 
   when committed will be prompt to define the remote repository.There you can 
   add the url to GIT repository.
   [image]

   Then enter the credentials for the repository and click 'Ok'.(Visual Studio 
   online Users need to enable "alternate authentication credentials" as 
   mentioned [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/overview) to login to repository)

   [image]

Comment: how can we do this for bitbucket . Is there a way like Github.??

Comment: @Nepster you should be able to connect with a bitbucket repo. if you add the your bitbucket repo url at the step 5 in the answer. Also if you need a dedicate plugin please try https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector, but unfortunately it seems the plugin is not supported or updated according to JetBrains.

Answer (score 39):

On Android Studio 1.0.2 you only need to go
VCS-> Import into Version control -> Share Project on GitHub.

Pop up will appear asking for the repo name.

Comment: When I try to do that, I get an error message saying, "Cannot run program "git.exe":CreateProcess error=2,The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: showing empty gist error and github repository opened

Comment: If you get the error above download latest git from https://git-scm.com/download/win and set the path to where you downloaded git.exe in Android Studio: File->Settings->Version Control->git "Path to Git executable" ; I had this issue hopefully will help others as well.

Comment: What about bitbucket . HOw to share project on Bitbucket ??

Answer (score 14):

In the version of Android Studio I have (0.3.2), it was as easy as using the menu.

> VCS Menu > Git > Share on GitHub.

It will then ask you for your credentials, and then a name for your new repo, and that's it!

Comment: In Android Studio 0.8.2 I found it via Alt+BackQuote or under VCS -> VCS Operations Popup.  In this version of Android Studio I don't see Git under the VCS menu.  If there's a plug-in or something I should have please let me know.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't specific to Android Studio, but a generic behaviour with Intellij's IDEA.

Go to: Preferences > Version Control > GitHub

Also note that you don't need the github integration: the standard git functions should be enough (VCS > Git, Tool Windows > Changes)

Answer (score 6):

## Android Studio 3.0

I love how easy this is in Android Studio.

### 1. Enter your GitHub login info

In Android Studio go to **File > Settings > Version Control > GitHub**. Then enter your GitHub username and password. (You only have to do this step once. For future projects you can skip it.)

[image]

### 2. Share your project

With your Android Studio project open, go to **VCS > Import into Version Control > Share Project on GitHub**.

Then click **Share** and **OK**.

[image]

That's all!

Answer (score 5):

For Android Studio 0.8.9: `VCS --> Import into version contraol --> Share project on Github.` It doesn't give you option to share in a specific repository or at least I couldn't find (my limitation!).

You can add your github info here: `File --> Settings --> Version COntraol --> Github.`

Answer (score 4):

Now you can do it like so (you do not need to go to github or open new directory from git):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First time I have added a video link for solving your problem but I learned it was a bad idea. This time I'll explain it briefly.

Android studio is compatible with github but you need adjust something:

1. Setup Android Studio
2. Setup the Github plugins in the Android Studio settings

   - Android Studio settings >> Plugins page
     [image]
3. Download the git version control system from this link and setup
   https://git-scm.com/
4. After the installation, open Android Studio settings page and select the git.exe

   - `settings >> version control >> git`
   - Usually the path to git.exe is `program files >> git >> bin >> git.exe`
5. Go to `Settings >> Version control >> Github` you will see login and password for your Github account. Apply the settings.
6. For updating the project, go in Android Studio top line click 
   `VCS >> enable version control integration >> git`
7. One more time 
   `VCS >> import into version control >> share project on Github`
   and enter your master password.

Now you can use VCS update buttons for updating your project to Github

Answer (score 1):

For existing project end existing repository with files:

```
git init
git remote add origin <.git>
git checkout -b master
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 0.8.2 , you have the same option (ie Share on GitHub). If you want to find it, you can use ctrl+shift+a and enter github in the input text.

Answer (score 0):

> Github with android studio

```
/*For New - Run these command in terminal*/
echo "# Your Repository" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository.git
git push -u origin master

/*For Exist - Run these command in terminal*/
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository.git
git push -u origin master
//git push -f origin master
//git push origin master --force

/*For Update - Run these command in terminal*/
git add .
git commit -m "your message"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got mine working using Android Studio UI:

Delete .git folder from your project folder.
Delete .git folder from all your project subfolders.

Open project in Android Studio.

Settings, Version Control, remove all the roots

Go to VCS, Import into VC, Create git repository

Select the directory

Make sure your folder is the only root in Settings, Version Control

Go to VCS, Import into VC, Share project on Github

Mark as private if wanted.

Select all the files for initial commit, including app folder

Add files, select all in your project folder and app folder.

VCS > Commit -> to commit the files.

VCS > Git > Push -> to push the files.