# My Android Project has are now Colored Red after Experimenting with CVS in android studio

Tags: git, github, android-studio

I am studying with the CVS in Android Studio and after that, my folder and all files are now color red. How can I make it back to normal again? Please check the link of the picture and see it.

http://imageshack.com/a/img199/8914/3sws.png

After further checking, probably this is the cause? I'm not sure if this error message means that it is succesfful.

http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6766/btac.png

This is my git (Git Release Notes (Git-1.8.4-preview20130916) I got this from this website.
http://msysgit.github.io/

Thanks,
Tok

Comment: Are you using [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) (which is a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control_system)) or [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System)? They're not the same and probably not used both at the same time.

Comment: I installed sysGit, I though Git and GitHub and CVS is the same.. oh my. I actually imported my codes to Github.. when i clone it, my files and folders are still collored red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch to **project view** in android studio,with **project selected**,
***right click*** >>>***git***>>>>then ***add***

wait for a few seconds and your files will change color.Provided you have already done your push that is and properly configured your git setup  as follows:
***Github/Bitbucket*:**

**1.create repository

**2.go to androidstudio:vcs::add version control**

**3.in android terminal:git init**

**4.git add --all>>>git remote add origin https:\yourrepo url**

**5.git commit -m "initial commit"**

**6.git push -u origin master(or whatever branch you created)**
refresh(github/bitbucket page)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know your programming environment, but in mine, with Git (CLI)

- my project files who changed (!= repository) are colored in red when no commit action have been executed.

  - this files become green after the commit action.

It's just an idea but your should try to commit your changes OR cancel (checkout) them.

Comment: How will you know if it is not equal to repository?  Where is the commit button? I can only see push, pull.  Sorry it is my first time on this...

Comment: Someone explain better than me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644946/how-do-you-sync-projects-to-github-with-android-studio

Comment: Hmmm maybe this is the cause?

Cannot find CVSROOT for file C:\Users\god-gavedmework\Documents\GitHub\PowerVolumeScreen\PowerVolumeScreen\src\main\java\com\toksis\powervolumescreen\MainPowerAndVolumeService.java

Comment: @ Jahnux73 maybe from your given link, maybe my cvs root is not setup properly... I had edited my question for further investigation. Maybe my setup is wrong? I have an error message. Please check my new picture link. thanks.

Comment: Your picture is bad resolution, can you write the error message or send better resolution picture ?

Answer (score 3):

Change your android project from android view to project view

Make sure you clicked on your project folder
On your toolbar
 1. Click on VCS
 2. Click on Git
 3. Click on Add

All your project files would be added to git

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a month ago, I am very confused with this problem. To fix this issue, you should delete `.idea/vcs.xml`, then restart your Android Studio. Good Luck!