# How to connect existing Android Studio project to existing Github organization repository

Tags: github, android-studio, version-control

Similar, but not quite the same as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345407/how-to-connect-existing-android-studio-project-to-existing-github-repository).

Maybe I did this in the wrong order.  I created my GitHub user, and I created a GitHub organization.  And, I created a repository under that organization.

I have a dump of code that was emailed to me that I've imported into Android Studio.  I have configured Android Studio with my GitHub username and password.

I have not yet created a local git repository.

I get the impression that if I use the Android Studio GUI, it will create a new repository under my username.  That's not what I want.  I want to connect this project to the organization repository.

I don't see any way to fully qualify the organization repository I want it to connect to.  Nor, do I see how to get at the organization relative to my username.

Maybe I should upload it manually to the organization repository?  Then, pull it down via the url to that repository?