# Git in Android Studio disappeared?

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control, settings

When I right-clicked in my Android Studio project (in the Android view), I used to have a **"Git"** submenu. There I could pull, push, etc.

However, that 'Git' menu is now gone, somehow. As a result, **I can neither push nor pull. Where can I enable that again?**

Comment: you can always use terminal.

Comment: close the project open again then it will show popup to add root. Add project to root git option will appear

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I already pressed ignore accidentically :( Can I trigger that again?

Comment: Please do not use tags that are irrelevant for the question.

Comment: Yes close the application delete it from recent list then open again that's it

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this way ,

1. In Android Studio enable the version control for the project by, VCS
   –> Enable Version Control Integration
2. Open command line/terminal and add the project to Git repository by,
   git   remote add
3. Add files by, VCS –> Git –> Add and commit/push by, VCS –> Commit
   Changes

Checkout [Android Studio Git Tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/) link for more detail.

as well as check this [Stack Explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682570/2826147).

> In Android Studio, go to **‘File’ –> ‘Settings’ –> ‘Version Control’ –>
>   ‘Git’.** Then click ‘Test’ to ensure that Git is configured properly in
>   Android Studio.
>
> Prior to using Git or any other version control with an existing
>   project, ‘version control integration’ should be enabled. In Android
>   Studio, got to ‘VCS’ –> ‘Enable Version Control Integration’. This
>   step is for an already existing project in Android Studio, that is not
>   is integrated with any version control.

Comment: VCS –> Enable Version Control Integration  , help me , thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case the plugins "Git" and "GitHub" ware disabled.
I enabled them (Settings->Plugins->Installed) and menu "Git" had been appeared.

Comment: Both Git and GitHub were already enabled in my case. However, I tried disabling both and then enabling them again. Restarted Android Studio and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Settings -> Plugins -> Install JetBrains Plugin -> Type "Git" on search

Then Install: VCS Annotations Preloader

Hope this process will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

A simple Gradle-Sync is fixing this for me. 
I had this after every "stash" or "unstash" now (Android Studio 3.5.3)

Answer (score 1):

just enable version control again 
VSC->enable version control

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have git repo on your project, just create a git repo on your project folder, something like

```
git init
```

and when you have git repo already, just close the project from android studio and re-open it. let android studio to refresh itself...

Answer (score 0):

at eventLog it will show error, git is not integrated. Press to integrate it and the problem will be resolved

Comment: How is it different from accepted answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34991098/7237062 ? How can you guess that the OP actually had an evenLog error ?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237062/lonewanderer I tried above mentioned way, but it was not useful, after an hour of trying I found this solution. So for the sake of other users to not spending so much time as I, I think that this answer deserves to be here

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for a while and ended up using the usual nuclear option to make Git show up: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...

[image]

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox and Git 2.32.0:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some reason I had two Directories under `Preferences -> Version Control`. One was the root of the repository (correct), the other one was root of the project (incorrect and colored red).

I couldn't check History or do any Git operation of any file.

Removing the red directory fixed it. I have no clue how it ended in there.

Answer (score -1):

I find that, if I clone the code with terminal, the Git menu is not among the options of VCS menu.

What I did was:

1. Click VCS menu.
2. Checkout from version control.
3. Select Git.
4. Fill all the necessary info in the popup window.
5. After cloning the code, there is a prompt saying Android Studio needs to be restarted. (Just restart it.)
6. The Git menu should appear after restarting Android Studio.