# Git Commit tab not showing up

Tags: android-studio

Can someone suggest another alternative in which I commit my projects into git? I'm used to right click on my project, go to Git and Add than commit but this time round when pressing Add the usual commit page isn't showing up.

Comment: Use the terminal?

Comment: Try in this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/34991098/6532155 else you can use terminal with git commands

Comment: Thanks for the replies, how can I do it from the terminal?@Zoe