# Push changes from android studio to Git

Tags: android, file-upload, github, zip, push

I am having a lot of trouble configuring Git on my laptop and integrate it with Android Studio. I won't provide further details on that, so I will go directly to the point.

I downloaded the code (zip format) from Github, so I can import it on Android Studio and work on it. But now I don't know how to push all the changes back to Github.

Is there a way or workaround to do that?

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16682570/4494555

Comment: use can push using `command prompt` or use `source tree `  it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not push directly. You should have permissions from admin who create that repository.

And Downloading the zip file is not correct way.

Once you have the permissions you can use git commands to pull and push code.

Let me know if you need further help regarding this.