# How to link IntelliJ IDEA/Android studio to git repositoty?

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Every time I am starting a new IntelliJ IDEA project I encounter the same problem: I want to link the project to a new git repository (like one that I created on Bitbucket.com). But it always takes ages to figure out how to set this up until I finally manage to do it. And when I start the next project I run into the same problem. So, I wanted to ask if anyone knows the exact steps I need to take to create a new project and link it to a new, empty repository.

Do I first create a new repository, clone it and then generate my project into that folder? I tried that but then Intellij IDEA keeps telling me there were no changes when I am trying to do my initial commit. Also, `git status` in the command line says there is nothing to commit.

If I create an empty repository and then create a new Project `File`>`New`>`From existing sources` my project is linked to the repository and I can commit. But I can generate a project anymore.

Can anyone summarize the process in a few simple steps? There must be a simple solution to this, but I can't figure it out :(

Comment: Learn how to use Git completely from the command line. Then you won't have to worry about using any IDE's Git functionality.

Comment: I agree with Sumner. You'll inevitably run into a situation where the IDE's VCS capability limits you - best to stick to command line, or failing that use a standalone Git GUI instead.

Comment: I know how to use git from the command line, but it is more convenient to have the git integration in my IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so for everyone who had the same problem as me. I solved my problem with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32893124/4118280) answer. Here is how you do it:

- Create a new repository on GitHub or Bitbucket or ...
- Create a new project in IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio
- Click `VCS` --> `Enable Version Control Integration`, select `Git`
- In the terminal go to the directory of your project and execute `git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>` (Bitbucket gives you the exact command when clicking `I have an existing project`)
- Right-click on your project name in the *Project* window and click `Git` -> `Add`.
- Click the `OK` button and you linked your project successfully
- Now, do your first commit: `VCS` -> `Commit Changes`