# I have cloned a repository in source tree how do I link source tree with android studio to reflect changes made

Tags: android, android-studio, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I cloned a repository from github into source tree and I would now like to know 
 I can link/connect source tree with android studio to reflect changes made in android studio can be reflected in source tree. If someone could please provide me with the steps to take, useful link and or tutorial thanks in advance

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32893124/3111083

Answer (score 0):

Open your project using an android studio, after some change you made you can see the reflection in source tree itself and in file explorer. Also, you can check the current checkout and branch. [image]

Also, you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644946/how-do-you-synchronise-projects-to-github-with-android-studio/32893124#32893124) for integrate with android studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your **Local repositories** at Source Tree is correct

[image]